# Application Halting on intent.PutExtra

Tags: c#, serialization, android-intent, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have created a button click handler, code of which goes like this

```
private void Next_imga2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Pothole p = new Pothole();
            p.waterLevel = selected;
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(createissue4));
            try
            {
                i.PutExtra("issueObj", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p));
                this.StartActivity(i);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, ex.ToString(), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            
            
        }
```

My application is stopping on

```
i.PutExtra("issueObj",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p));
```

I can't really understand why this is causing application to stop, when this line occurs the app stops and visual studio automatically starts to debug the app again.

I have tried:

1. applying the try/catch block so to make sure that it is not an exception that is causing this.
2. making sure that pothole class object "p" is not null.
3. making sure that this method is being executed on button click

Answer (score 1):

Write JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p) in the separate line and check whether this line of code is causing issue.

And you can check the application output window, if any crash log availability.

I have tried same kind of code and have not observed any crash.

Comment: I am new to programming, can you tell me how to look for output windows when debugging

Comment: In the output window of console pannel.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio for Mac, then bottom of the IDE you can see a tap with "Application Output - ProjectName". If its not available then you can enable by selecting menu View -> Other Windows -> Application Output - ProjectName.

Comment: Actually, this activity was not halting it was the opened activity4 that contained an error